# ffmpeg on Heroku, EC2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined , ffmpegProc.stdout.on('data', function(data) { ^

Tags: node.js, heroku, ffmpeg, runtime-error, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg.exe to convert video to audio .
On local machine it works fine but when deployed on heroku server it throws error like....

`/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:190
 ffmpegProc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

Please help me ....!

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I found the problem.
I was giving path of ffmpeg.exe for linux machine also.

I had deployed my app on aws ec2 linux machine.

I installed ffmpeg from here [download ffmpeg for linux](https://medium.com/@maskaravivek/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ec2-running-amazon-linux-451e4a8e2694)

Now I gave ffmpeg path appropriately in node js app.
For me this was **/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.2.2-amd64-static/ffmpeg**

Finally , it worked. God...!